# PHP xmlreader 404 error

Tags: php, xmlreader

I'm running an XMLREADER to pull in various XML files and then parse it with SimpleXML in PHP5.   This is working but for a particular file (around 4.5MB file size) it results in

> Warning: `XMLReader::open(http://www.blah.com/adm/feeds/The XML File.xml)` [xmlreader.open]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /public_html/adm/cache/parsers/parser.php on line 15

But when I click ont the url listed the file is there. I've tested this on a similar dedicated server to mine and the problem doesn't happen.

Any ideas what might be going wrong? In summary the file is there but XMLREADER reports a 404 trying to open it.

Comment: Make sure www.blah.com resolves to the same IP address on your server as the one you get when accessing it from your browser.

Comment: Also, why are you using XMLReader _and_ SimpleXML? In general you only need to use one - the former is good for large documents, as it uses a forward-only file cursor through the XML, and SimpleXML is good for random access as it loads everything into memory.

Comment: Presumably the file parser.php is in itself being found? Make sure you can `echo` from this and get some output `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this helps anyone - it was the filename that was the problem, it had a space in it which the host I'm on didn't like.  Never had that problem on other hosts!  Live an learn.

Brett